"Second Mutable Borrow" in Rust.. but I never meant to do the first
I'm learning Rust and trying to understand how to think about the following situation I'm stuck on:

I take mutable struct into a function
I want to a method on it in two different places that will mutate it

In Python pseudocode:
def add_stuff(c):
  c.add("Hi")
  c.add("there")

But when I compile, I get this error:
error[E0505]: cannot move out of `c` because it is borrowed
  --> src/lib.rs:47:12
   |
40 |   fn make_and_maybe_load<'a>() -> Container<'a> {
   |                          -- lifetime `'a` defined here
41 |     let mut c = Container::new();
   |         ----- binding `c` declared here
42 |     maybe_load(&mut c, Some("HI"));
   |                ------ borrow of `c` occurs here
...
47 |     return c
   |            ^
   |            |
   |            move out of `c` occurs here
   |            returning this value requires that `c` is borrowed for `'a`rror[E0505]: cannot move out of `c` because it is borrowed

Here is a full working example in Rust that will generate this error:
pub struct Container<'a> {
    items: Vec<&'a str>
}

impl<'a> Container<'a> {
    pub fn new() -> Self {
      Self {
        items: Vec::new()
      }
    }
  
    pub fn add_item(&'a mut self, item: &'a str) {
      self.items.push(item);
    }
  }
  
  impl<'a> Default for Container<'a> {
    fn default() -> Self {
        Self::new()
    }
  }

  fn maybe_load<'a>(c:&'a mut Container<'a>, i: Option<&'a str>) {  
    match i {
        Some(i) => {
            // first mutable borrow occurs here
            // argument requires that `*c` is borrowed for `'a`
            c.add_item(i);
        },
        None => {
            // Do nothing
        }
    }

    // Compiler:
    // second mutable borrow occurs here
    c.add_item("Hello");
}
  
  fn make_and_maybe_load<'a>() -> Container<'a> {
    let mut c = Container::new();
    maybe_load(&mut c, Some("HI"));

    // COMPILER:
    // move out of `c` occurs here
    // returning this value requires that `c` is borrowed for `'a`
    return c
  }

I realize this is a silly example – I'm just trying to learn how to manipulate data in Rust, hoping that I'd run aground in situations exactly like this so I can figure out why.

Do not use 'a on the reference. It is unnecessary and causing your problem. playground

Also &'a [mut?] Container<'a> is almost always wrong.

@kmdreko is there any value to having <'a> on the Struct? or is that just completely unnecessary as a default?

Container needs 'a in its definition since it has members with lifetimes (&'a str), whether you need to annotate it when you use it depends on whether it needs to be constrained (it is required on add_item and maybe_load since it must match the str argument's lifetime) or if the compiler can't deduce it (like for make_and_maybe_load).
